# Custom Controller that mimics standard controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

I want to use a visualforce page as a Global Action but according to documentation I need to create a custom controller. I am not doing anything outside of the standard controller so I am wondering if there is a way to mimic the standard controller.

Here is my visualforce page. Is it super simple to create a custom controller?

```
 <apex:page standardController="Contest_Tracking__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <!-- Page Header -->
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Contest Entry" subtitle="New Contest Entry" />
    <!-- Begin Form -->
    <apex:form style="width:90%;margin:auto;" >
        <apex:image value="http://web-staging.leveleleven.com/wp-content/themes/LevelEleven/images/header-logo-red-2x.png" styleClass="logo" />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contest Rules" mode="edit" >
            <!-- Enter Contest --> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="true" title="Create Contest Entry">
                <!--apex:inputField value="{!Contest_Tracking__c.Picklist_Contest_Name__c}" required="true"  onchange=""/ -->
                <apex:outputLabel value="Contest Name"/>
                             <apex:actionRegion >
                              <apex:inputField value="{!Contest_Tracking__c.Picklist_Contest_Name__c}">
                              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="MarchMadness" />
                              </apex:inputField>
                             </apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Contest Vote"/>
                             <apex:actionRegion >
                              <apex:inputField value="{!Contest_Tracking__c.Picklist_Contest_Vote__c}">
                              </apex:inputField>
                             </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <!-- Button Section -->
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit Entry" action="{!save}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <!-- Rules -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true" title="Contest Rules">
                <apex:pageblocksection id="MarchMadness" columns="1">
                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="rules" style="width:80%" rendered="{!Contest_Tracking__c.Picklist_Contest_Name__c == 'March Madness'}">
                    1. Be sure to complete you bracket at CBS Sport to be eligible for prizes.<br />
                    2. Guess your champion here to earn 10 points for Culture Club.<br /> <br />
                    If you did not get a CBS Sports bracket invitation, please email Jim Oman.<br /><br />
                </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        .logo {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
        margin: -65px 20px 0 0;
        padding: 20px;
        }
        .rules {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;     
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: what makes you think you would need a custom controller?  If you're just using the fields from the object and the standard save method, then you wouldn't need one unless there's advanced logic you need to provide.

Comment: I tried to create a Global Action with this page but it doesn't show up in the list. When I googled the issue I found documentation saying that you can't use Standard Controllers.

Comment: Link to article, comment is right under the gray boxes at the top.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_actions_vf_pages_for_global_actions.htm&language=en_US